# NetBeans doesn't find projects on OneDrive

Tags: java, netbeans, projects, onedrive

I have a pc and a laptop both running Windows Pro 8.1 and latest version of Netbeans. I log on the pc and the laptop with the same hotmail/windows account. I build my java projects on the pc and i save them on a OneDrive directory just fine all working ok. **BUT** when i try to open them on my laptop NetBeans sees the folders with all the files in them but doesnt find the projects so it is unable to open them. So i cant edit or work on any of my projects on my laptop. Is using a usb drive to save my projects my only way to mobility?

Comment: Seems like either OneDrive isn't syncing the project file or NetBeans can't handle it for some reason. Are the OneDrive folders located in the **exact** same place on both machines?

Comment: Try to zip the project and then unzip on your second device so that hidden files get synced

Answer (score 1):

Turn off "Compile on save" for the project:
[project name]-> Properties -> Build -> Compiling.

This removes the project's build subdirectory, whose contents include

```
build/classes/.netbeans_automatic_build
build/classes/.netbeans_update_resources.
```

OneDrive sees these files as nameless with long extensions.

You can enable "Compile on save" in working sessions if desired,
just disable it when you want to make it available to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ensure the files are available offline. Windows 8.1 and OneDrive use a feature of Windows where files appear to be in a folder but may not actually be there yet (because they are in the cloud). While most applications are able to trigger files to be downloaded when opened, not all applications are compatible.

Try forcing the folder to be available offline by right clicking on the folder and selecting "Make available offline" and see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans along with a number of other multiplatform applications tend to save configuration files in .settings/.configuration files.  And unfortunately as of today the OneDrive client does not support syncing files the begin with a period.  The OneDrive team is aware of this limitation and is looking into fixing this.

Not great solution, but a potential work around:
- Stick your NetBeans projects in a zip, 7z, tar or whatever convenient packaging format of your choice would be before you leave that machine.

Ultimately it sounds like your scenario is around using source control.  While it is certainly not as easy as just using sync'ed folder, you could use a source control management tool like [SVN](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialHosting), or [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109440/best-git-repository-hosting-for-a-commercial-project).